# How can I speed up OpenOffice Calc Macro that updates many cells?

Tags: performance, openoffice-calc, openoffice-basic

I have an OpenOffice Calc macro (in Basic) that rounds all numbers in the active worksheet to a given number of decimal places. It takes about 4 seconds to process 100 rows of a 9000 row spreadsheet. Each row has 35 columns, of which 19 columns are numeric.

How can I make this execute faster? This is the first macro I have ever written for OpenOffice, so it is likely there are faster methods that I have never heard of. Here is my code:

```
Dim oFunction as Object 


' Round all Value cells (cells that do not contain Text or Functions) on the current sheet to as many decimal places as user requests.
Sub RoundUsedCells

Dim  oSheet As Object, oUsedRange as Object, oCursor as Object, oCell As Object
Dim row, column,lastRow, lastColumn
Dim places$, placesToRound
Dim roundedValue as Double

' Ask user how many decimal places to round
places$ = InputBox ("Round to how many places (leave blank to cancel)?")
if (places$ is Nothing or places$ = "") then
    ' Do nothing.
else
    placesToRound = CInt(places$)

    ' Get the currently active sheet.
    oSheet = thiscomponent.getcurrentcontroller.activesheet

    ' Create a one cell range at the origin,
    ' then create a cursor that allows us to extend the range to include all the "used" cells.
    ' The cursor will then allow us to find out how large is that used range.
    oUsedRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByPosition(0,0,0,0)
    oCursor = oSheet.createCursorByRange(oUsedRange)
    oCursor.GotoEndOfUsedArea(false)    

    ' Obtain the last rows and colums in the "used" range from the cursor.
    lastRow = oCursor.RangeAddress.EndRow  
    lastColumn = oCursor.RangeAddress.EndColumn 

    ' Loop through all cells from the origin (0,0) to the last used column and row.
    for row = 0 to lastRow
        if (row mod 50 = 0) then
            StatusBar "Rounding row " + (row + 1) + " of " + (lastRow + 1) + "..."
        endif
        for column = 0 to lastColumn
            oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(column, row)
            Select Case oCell.Type 
                Case com.sun.star.table.CellContentType.VALUE
                   ' Only round value cells. Skip over empty cells, formuls and text.
                   roundedValue = Round(oCell.Value, placesToRound)
                   if (roundedValue <> oCell.Value) then
                        oCell.Value = roundedValue
                   endif
                Case com.sun.star.table.CellContentType.EMPTY 
                Case com.sun.star.table.CellContentType.TEXT       
                Case com.sun.star.table.CellContentType.FORMULA

            End Select  
        next column
    next row
    StatusBar "Rounding complete."
endif
End Sub

' Obtain access to worksheet functions, such as the "round" function.
Sub InitRound 
    if (oFunction is Nothing) then
        oFunction = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess") 
    endif
End Sub 

' Round the value to the given number of places after the decimal.
Function Round(value, decimalPlaces) 
   InitRound() 
   Dim args( 1 to 2 ) As Variant 
   args(1) = value 
   args(2) = decimalPlaces 
   Round = oFunction.callFunction( "round", args() ) 
End Function

global vStatusBarText as string '=text that is been displayed on the statusbar
sub StatusBar(optional vNewText, optional vAddText) 'set or add text to the statusbar, nothing = clear&reset it.
   if isError(vNewText) then
      if isError(vAddText) then 'clear statusbar
         vStatusBarText=""
      else 'add text to the previous statusbar
         vStatusBarText=vStatusBarText & vAddText 
      endif
   else
      if isError(vAddText) then 'use new text
         vStatusBarText=vNewText
      else 'use new text and add the other text as well
         vStatusBarText=vNewText & vAddText
      endif
   endif
   vStatusBarText=right(vStatusBarText,int(ThisComponent.CurrentController.VisibleArea.Width/150)) 'Select last part that could be displayed.
   if isNull(ThisComponent.CurrentController) then exit sub 'Because the last XEventListener-event can't be written to the statusbar, because it's no longer there!
   if vStatusBarText="" then 'reset statusbar
      ThisComponent.CurrentController.StatusIndicator.Reset
   else 'change the text in the statusbar
      ThisComponent.CurrentController.StatusIndicator.Start(vStatusBarText,0)
   endif
end sub
```

UPDATE: I rewrote Round to not call out to Calc, which doubled the speed. It is still too slow. Must do much better than fifty rows per second.

```
Function Round2(value, decimalPlaces) as Double
    Round2 = Int(value * 10 ^ decimalPlaces + 0.5) / 10 ^ decimalPlaces
   'Dim multiplier as Double, bigValue as Double
   'multiplier = 10 ^ decimalPlaces
   'bigValue = (value * multiplier) + 0.5
   'Round2 = CDbl( CLng(bigValue) ) / multiplier  
End Function
```

UPDATE 2:

Found a way to disable automatic updates and screen refresh during macro execution which triples the speed again (now it is 200 rows per second):

```
myDoc = ThisComponent
myDoc.lockControllers()
myDoc.addActionLock()
' --- modify your cells here ---
myDoc.removeActionLock()
myDoc.unlockControllers()
```

Comment: Do you really need the numbers rounded, or do you just want them to be displayed with a specific number of decimal points? If the latter, then it's just a matter of applying the formatting (once)...

Comment: This function is part of a workflow for comparing two Worksheets. I am pasting in results from SQL Server of two queries (legacy and optimized), and I need to know if the results match. The numerical values often differ in the eleventh or twelfth decimal place, which I do not want flagged as a difference. Thus I am forcing the rounding. I suppose I could make the comparison fuzzy and not actually change the values...

Comment: I am thinking that the recalc engine might be interfering. Is there a way to turn recalc off and on?

Comment: Found how to disable recalc and added to question. Much better performance. If I could double the speed once more, I would be happy.

Answer (score 1):

My timing tests indicate that your biggest issue is that you are accessing once cell at a time. My testing indicates that there are two approaches to dramatically increase this type of operation.

The most effective method is to use some native facility to do this; for example, to set the display style to show in a particular format that will round the display at the specified point if that is possible.

The next best solution is to get the data in chunks and update the data in chunks. The method you use to get the data will depend on the uniformity of the data. For example, getDataArray() and setDataArray() is probably about 100 times faster (at least) then looking at one cell at a time. There are two different possible methods here:

getData() will Get numerical data as a nested sequence of values (arrays in an array).

getDataArray() is the same as getData() but may contain String or Double.